# cloudkit: validate a developer ID-signed application error: the archived application has entitlements that require Mac app store distribution

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6, cloudkit

I'm working in Mac app using cloudkit but when I tried to "validate a developer ID-signed application" for adhoc distribution I get this error:

"the archived application has entitlements that require Mac app store distribution. The invalid entitlements were: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier"

[image]

This only happens when I have include cloudKit. Any of you knows what can I be doing wrong or how to fix this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CloudKit is an app service available only to apps distributed through
>   the App Store and Mac App Store.

So you won't be able to use Cloudkit in a Developer ID signed app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html

Answer (score 0):

This entitlement points to the iCloud Key-Value Store, not to CloudKit.

This error message can be ignored, as far I know. Apps exported as Developer ID-signed Application that includes this entitlement work as expected.